# Using Reactive Extensions, how can I ignore a sequence of characters based on delimiters?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx.net

I have an app that uses Rx to receive data from a device on the serial port. So I have an `IObservable<char>` that I slice and dice into various strings. However, the device vendor added some debugging information that is enclosed in braces:

> `interesting stuff {debug stuff} interesting stuff`

```
source ---a-b-c-{-d-e-b-u-g-}-d-e-f---|
          | | |               | | |
output ---a-b-c---------------d-e-f---|
```

I need to filter out (discard, ignore) the `{debug stuff}` from my character sequence?. Is there a simple way to do that? "When you see this character, ignore elements until you see this other character".

I looked at Until but that would terminate the sequence and I don't want that to happen...

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want, assuming no nested or unbalanced brackets.

```
source
    .Scan((prev, c) =>
    {
        if (prev == '{')
            return c == '}' ? c : '{';
        else
            return c;
    })
    .Where(c => c != '{' && c != '}')
```

It converts everything after the `{` into `{` until the `}`, then filters out all braces. The diagrammed output is:

```
source ---a-b-c-{-d-e-b-u-g-}-d-e-f---|
scan   ---a-b-c-{-{-{-{-{-{-}-d-e-f---|
          | | |               | | |
where  ---a-b-c---------------d-e-f---|
```

Comment: OK thanks, I think I see what you're doing there. SO I think that essentially converts everything after the first brace into a left-brace character, until the right brace; then filters out braces. I'll give that a go.